# What MMo Rpg/ Open World game can I play If i am a Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

I have been looking for mmorpg games for the past couple of days to play. But all of the games i have come across like genshin impact have revealing female characters so i can't play the game if that is the case( **I think let me know if that's not the case**). So can anyone tell me some mmorpg games/open world games without these characters.

Comment: Please ask questions related to Islam here. This has nothing to do with Islam.

Answer (score 0):

in Islam we do not discourage about the video games. Furthermore, you can play San Andreas Multiplayer, it has many muslim brothers playing it with you, other MMORPG have christian undertones, and this is bid'ah so not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the female figures in the game could lead you to forbidden things, the best thing to do is to avoid them, as what comes next could drown you into sins.